# c++ socket data send c# data receive

Tags: c#, c++, sockets

I'm trying to send some data with header from c++ tcp socket to c# tcp socket. Please see my code below for this appraoch.

C++ code to send data

```
typedef struct tag_TCP_Header_Data{
  int iMessageID;
  int iDataLen;
  int iCheckSum;
}TCP_HEADER_DATA;

  TCP_HEADER_DATA stTcpHeader = {0};
  char acSendBuf[1024] = {0};  
  char chData[38] = "01 April - I compile my simple program";

  stTcpHeader.iMessageID  = 100;
  stTcpHeader.iDataLen    = 38;
  stTcpHeader.iCheckSum   = 190;

  memcpy(acSendBuf, &stTcpHeader, sizeof(stTcpHeader));
  memcpy(acSendBuf+sizeof(stTcpHeader), &chData, sizeof(chData));

  int iSent = SendSocketData(acSendBuf, sizeof(acSendBuf));
```

C# code to receive data

```
public void AddBytesFromArrayToArrayList(ref ArrayList arrayListReceivedBytes, byte[] byteReceivedBuffer, int intLength)
{
  for (int intCount = 0; intCount < intLength; intCount++)
  {
    arrayListReceivedBytes.Add(byteReceivedBuffer[intCount]);
  }
}

public byte[] ReceiveMessage()
{
  lock (this.objectToLock)
  {
    byte[] byteReceivedBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int intBytesReceived = 0;
    ArrayList arrayListReceivedBytes = new ArrayList();
    do
    {
      try
      {
        intBytesReceived = this.socket.Receive(byteReceivedBuffer, byteReceivedBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        this.AddBytesFromArrayToArrayList(ref arrayListReceivedBytes, byteReceivedBuffer, intBytesReceived);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
      }
      catch (SocketException ex)
      {
        string str = ex.Message;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        string str = ex.Message;
      }
    }
    while (this.socket.Available > 0);
    byte[] byteReceived = (byte[])arrayListReceivedBytes.ToArray(typeof(byte));
    return byteReceived;
  }
}
```

Server gets the header data with blank in between like this. I know something I'm missing in c# code for this int and char byte data conversion. Can anyone point me out?

```
[0]  100    byte
[1]  0      byte
[2]  0      byte
[3]  0      byte
[4]  160    byte
[5]  0      byte
[6]  0      byte
[7]  0      byte
[8]  190    byte
[9]  0      byte
[10] 0      byte
[11] 0      byte

[12] Correct data
[..] Correct data
[..] Correct data
```

Comment: All is fine,  your c++ header contains 3 ints which maps to 12 c# bytes.

Comment: An integer consists of 4 bytes. If you want to see the other bytes get used, send in a value greater than 255.

Comment: So with my code I will always have to parse header at the c# code like byte[0] = messageID, byte[4] = dataLen, byte[8] = checkSum. This position of byte array should always indicate the same. Am I correct?